# How to accomplish this splitter effect in code?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This comes from Dictionary APP in 10.7 Lion. Is this a NSShadow in a NSSplitView? I'd appreciate any advice, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, Li Fumin, for reminding me this was one of those visual effects I wanted to solve. :-) here's [some sample code](http://joshua.nozzi.name/2011/07/the-recessed-list-effect/) I posted just a bit ago. Enjoy!

Comment: Hi, Joshua, I have read your code. It seems like the effect in your code and the effect in Dictionary APP are not exactly the same thing. In the Dictionary App, texts can go under the splitter shadow, and at the bottom or top of the table view, it applys too. Thanks for your advice,though.

Comment: And I get some inspirations from this post. But I want to implement this in high level framework rather than low level CoreGraphics. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366362/how-to-draw-a-tapered-line-oval-shadow-in-cocoa

Comment: Actually, the text *doesn't* go under the shadow. If you zoom in and watch as the shadow moves, the text does not change color. The shadow is in fact *under* the text. Could you be referencing the fact the text doesn't truncate in my example? That's a simple toggle for table column data cell behavior...

Comment: But in your sample code what I saw was that texts can't overlap the shadow which Dictionary APP actually can.It is subtle but important difference.

Comment: Some extra configuration is necessary. You can set the table's intercell spacing to {0.0, somevalue}. That'll get you most of the way there. The text cell itself is doing some extra stuff to keep the text truncated away from the edge (it'll adjust kerning, etc.). That's left up to you. For proof it works, however, set the gradient width to 8 (vs 4) in lines 63 and 64 of JLNRecessedTableView.m. The gradient is *definitely* under the text.

Comment: Justification for not adding this behavior to the view subclasses: it may be unwanted and should be app-specific. I just posted an updated version including the intercell spacing demo (it's in the app controller's startup logic).

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting it with [F-Script](http://www.fscript.org/) shows that it’s a custom split view (`DSIndexSplitView`) with a custom table view (`DSIndexTableView`) in the right column – nothing very surprising. The shadow is part of the table view rather than the splitter (which on further consideration can also be seen by the fact that text in the table view can draw over it).

I’d guess it’s either a gradient or an NSShadow drawn into the table view, before passing off to the superclass to render the cells.

Comment: If it is a shadow over the splitter, it is still possible to draw texts under the shadow.In this case, the splitter can be very thin.Is that right?But I don't know how to code this.