# Objective-C title bar and list examples?

Tags: objective-c, macos, user-interface

I'm pretty new to the world of Objective-C. I've stumbled across an interface that I really like. Can anyone give me any pointers (or examples) on how to create; 1) A title bar like the one below. 2) A list like the one below?

(image: http://dribbble.com/shots/204701-Instant-Message-App-Idea-take-3?list=show)

Thanks!

Comment: Don't want to sound rude, but SO is for specific questions and answers that can be answered here, not linking to off-site resources or for generic questions "How do I make this?".

Comment: He is just looking where to start. His question is alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to cocoa, In case of cocoa you will not get the over all idea from a single source. So google your need effectively. I googled for you and i got [INAppStoreWindow](https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow) for you. Just change the height and add tool bar with needed controls.

and look at the following links for lists

[#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15734781/2515572)
[#2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8749311/2515572)
[#3](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/mac-os-x/controls?sort=rating)
[#4](http://markbrownsword.wordpress.com/category/technical/)
[#5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366362/how-to-draw-a-tapered-line-oval-shadow-in-cocoa)
Happy to help !